# CMYK Color Format wColorPicker.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I am using [wColorPicker.js](https://github.com/websanova/wColorPicker#wcolorpickerjs]) for colour picker and at many places its response is being used but I need to use CMYK colors in place of RGB now for this library and not getting any option to do so. Please help me.

Comment: what library? is it ok to convert from rgb to cmyk, or do you want another colorpicker? can you copy what you need from https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_cmyk.asp ?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I do not want to change another library just want to change how easily I could use its cmyk converted colors in color pallete.

Comment: well I got a solution

Comment: in its wColorPicker.js file there is an array of colors by changing those color array it could be achieved

Comment: But it is not the exact solution as there is no direct mode changing method this is just a patch I think

Comment: We are also using this and for print media we also need it to show as cmyk.